# How to create and play playlist in XML format with jPlayer

Tags: xml, jplayer, playlist

I wanted to know how can I create a playlist in XML and then play that playlist by using jPlayer on my site.

Comment: Your question is impossible to answer as we don't have much details about the languages you use for your site. We don't know what you have tried so far and what problems you have experienced. This forum is made fofr that kind of questions. If not, it will be considered off topic and down voted. I then suggest you talk about what you got trough and show some code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code as the starting point:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var cssSelector = { jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_1", cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1" };
   var options = { swfPath: "../js", supplied: "ogg, mp3" };
   var myPlaylist = new jPlayerPlaylist(cssSelector, [], options);

   $.get("xml_audio.php", {}, function (xml){
      $('Track', xml).each(function (i){
         var title = $(this).attr('title');
         var track_name = $(this).attr('track_name');

         myPlaylist.add({ 
            'title': title, 
            'mp3': 'audio/' + track_name + '.mp3', 
            'ogg': 'audio/' + track_name + '.ogg' 
         });
      });
   });
});
```

Alternatively, please take a look at [jPlayer Jukebox add-on](http://www.gyrocode.com/projects/jplayer-jukebox/). It is based on [jPlayer Playlist add-on](http://www.jplayer.org/latest/demo-02-jPlayerPlaylist/) but adds extra functionality, such as ability to scan the page for media links and make them playable. It now supports playlists in [XSPF](http://xspf.xiph.org/) format.

[image: jPlayer Jukebox add-on]